# Check the CSV file encoding in Data Factory

Tags: csv, encoding, azure-data-factory

I am implementing a pipeline to move csv files from one folder to another in a data lake with the condition that the CSV file is encoded in UTF8.

Is it possible to check the encoding of a csv file directly in data factory/data flow?

Actually, the encoding is set in the connection conditions of the dataset. What happens in this case, if the encoding of the csv file is different?

What happens at the database level if the csv file is staged with a wrong encoding?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The default encoding is UTF8, we must manually set it during copy if the encode is different. If you don't set it, data factory will convert it to UTF8.

Comment: I don't think that's something you can do natively within Azure Data Factory so the approach would be to use ADF's orchestration abilities and call out to something which could do this check, for example an Azure Function, Azure Batch Service, a Databricks Notebook, a Synapse Notebook etc

Comment: I second the Azure Function approach.

Comment: Hi @user0987654321, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Done! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for now, we can't check the file encoding in Data Factory/Data Flow directly. We must per-set the encoding type to read/write test files:
[image]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text#dataset-properties

The Data Factory default file encoding is `UTF-8`.

Like @wBob said, you need to achieve the encoding check in code level, like Azure Function or Notebook and so on. Call these actives in pipeline.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to detect UTF16 by reading the file as rows of UTF8 with no delimiter and examining the first two bytes as they will then be separately visible.   If their hex value is FFFE or FEFF the file is 16 bit UTF.  Search wikipedia for 'Byte Order Mark' to see why this works.

Unfortunately with ANSI, UTF8 and other formats as they either have no such marker or it will disappear during the load if the file is actually UTF8.  So no help there.

BTW if you want to know a file's type manually on sample data and then hard code the ingesting dataset to use the right type, open it in Notepad and look at the bottom right corner.  Notepad will do the detective work for you and flag it there.

If the encoding is unpredictable - well you have trouble :)