# Checking data in CSV file with Data Factory

Tags: csv, encoding, azure-data-factory

I am implementing a pipeline to move csv files from one folder to another in a data lake. However, this should be done only if the csv files comply to some conditions regarding the delimiter, the strings that should be between quotes, no header, specific row delimiter...

At the moment, I am able to do the check by setting the connection conditions (rules) in the dataset and then analyzing the names and number of columns compared to what it is expected for each csv file.

But since I am using a get Metadata activity, I actually check the first row only and I have no guaranty that the rest of the rows comply to the conditions too (except for the "no header" condition).

In this case, which other robust and reasonable alternative do we have to check the complete file? knowing that the file could contain millions of rows and that the check could be done many times until the file is corrected and the conditions are met.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check the CSV file encoding in Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66255548/check-the-csv-file-encoding-in-data-factory)

Comment: The two questions address two different topics although both are related to Data Factory/Data Flow:
 
1. how to check the encoding in the CSV file,

2. and, how to check a COMPLETE CSV file for specific conditions in Data Factory/Data Flow.

Comment: Hi @user0987654321, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: I kept your answer @Joseph Xu.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what the answer sais of your previous post, the Data Factory default file encoding is UTF-8. You also can check your COMPLETE CSV file via Azure Function, Azure Batch Service, a Databricks Notebook, a Synapse Notebook etc.

In Azure data factory, we only can use [column pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern) to check specify column content or all columns content.

For example:

1. This is my source csv files. I set the `age` column type as `short`.
   [image]
2. In `DerivedColumn1`, I use column pattern and enter `$$>29` to determine the value of the third column.
   [image]
3. The debug value is as follows:
   [image]

In Azure Data factory data flow, we only can do this.